# Accessing CRS of feature-collection

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, feature-collection

I was looking for a function/way to print crs of feature collection on GEE.
I thought using the same method as applied on image will give me the crs, but it didnt.

The method I used for image:

```
print(img.Projection().getInfo())
```

Is there any similar way to get the projection for featurecollection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all features in the collection have the same projection, you can get the projection from the geometry of the first feature:

```
print(
  collection.first().geometry().projection()
)
```

Comment: I would recommend `collection.first().geometry().projection().getInfo()` since `print` will only give you the structure of the method chain that is inserted into it. At least, that was what I got when calling the statement above